# Need HEX values expected by various WinSCard APIs

Tags: c#, .net, smartcard, winscard

We are trying to use smart card to authenticate user into the application running on Windows 7 machine. We are using `WinSCard` DLL but we do not understand exact `HEX` values to pass to various APIs like `SCardDisconnect` etc.

Could you please refer me to list of required HEX values or any other forum/link which could be helpful while working with `WinSCard.dll`?

Comment: @downvoters : I do not understand why some people have downvoted for this question? Please post some comment so that other readers and I'll come to know the reason behind it. I wanted some reference material to understand WinSCard APIs better and so I asked for the reference material through this question; anything wrong in that?

Comment: I think most people found this question/answer to be too trivial. To use a library you use the constants defined for that library. You are not helping yourself by supplying the answer so fast. It shows it was trivial, and you don't leave much room for others to respond.

Comment: @owlstead: Thanks for your comment. I already knew the APIs; I was stuck at the HEX values/constants only! And I posted answer immediately because I found necessary things so fast; however this cannot be the reason for downvoting! Anyway, thanks for your comments. I have updated answer with more helpful information related to WinScard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try WinSCard.h, reference: http://www.koders.com/c/fid8255BD4EBC4D3984B6D444CFF8213E654028A588.aspx

Some other helpful references related to this topic:

- [The Smart Card Cryptographic Service Provider Cookbook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms953432.aspx)
- [Smart Card SDK functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#smart_card_functions)

Comment: Hi there. Fortunately stackoverflow understands naked URL's, no need for that double copy. Please include some explanation in your answers, not just a link (even if the asker, well, asked for it).